# Exception sending data from a DataGridViewComboBox to a TextBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So far I managed to handle the event when the value of the comboBox is changed, but when I want to update the content of another cell with that value I'm receiving a 'System.NullReferenceException'.

This is the code I'm using to handle the event (I found it in another question)

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridBebidas.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        // This fires the cell value changed handler below
        dataGridBebidas.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // My combobox column is the second one so I hard coded a 1, flavor to taste
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridBebidas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4];
        if (cb.Value != null)
        {
            // Asigno valor de combobox a campo "Alcohol"
            dataGridBebidas.Invalidate();

            var currentcell = dataGridBebidas.CurrentCellAddress;
            var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridBebidas.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[3]; // Cell I want to update

            cel.Value = sendingCB.EditingControlFormattedValue.ToString(); // Asign value of the combobox

        }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is what you want.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridBebidas.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        // This fires the cell value changed handler below
        dataGridBebidas.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // My combobox column is the second one so I hard coded a 1, flavor to taste
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridBebidas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4];
    if (cb.Value != null)
    {
        // Asigno valor de combobox a campo "Alcohol"
        dataGridBebidas.Invalidate();

        dataGridBebidas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = cb.Value; // Cell I want to update
    }
}
```